# Why do you use df twice to get a list of duplicate rows based on the values of a single column in a CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am new to programming and one of the tasks I have created for myself is to identify all of the duplicate contacts in our Zoho CRM and to merge them. I exported a CSV file of our contacts and used pandas to create a DataFrame from the csv file.

Now I want to get a list of all the rows with duplicate contacts, based on the Full Name column. After googling around, I came across this link which explains how to do that:

https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-get-list-of-all-duplicate-rows/

The part I don't understand is why we "use" (I am not sure what the correct terminology is) df twice:

```
df2 = df[df.duplicated('Full Name')]
```

Why doesn't this work?

```
df.duplicated('Full Name')
```

Comment: That just returns a series of indexes, you need to nest it to get the rows at those indexes.

Answer (score 1):

`duplicated` returns a boolean Series, which you can use for many things other than [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Example of the output of `duplicated`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1,2,3,2,2]})
df.duplicated('col')
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Boolean indexing (`df[df.duplicated('col')]`) will keep all rows for which the passed boolean is True at the corresponding position/index.

##### but why 2 steps?

To drop the duplicate there is the [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) method, to filter out the rows in one step.

However, in your case you want to **keep** the duplicates so you have to use boolean indexing.